# PHP recursive copy directories to single directory

Tags: php, recursion

In PHP I want to recursively copy all the files from a directory and it's sub-directories to a single directory *with no sub-directories*.

e.g.

.../dir/subdir1/file1.pdf

.../dir/subdir1/file2.pdf

.../dir/subdir2/file3.pdf

.../dir/subdir2/file4.pdf

should become:

.../newdir/file1.pdf

.../newdir/file2.pdf

.../newdir/file3.pdf

.../newdir/file4.pdf

ie. there is no 'subdir' level anymore.

I am using this PHP code, it copies all the files but it is retaining the subdirectories which is not desired:

```
<?php
$src = "/dir/";
$dst = "/newdir/";

function recurse_copy($src,$dst) { 
    $dir = opendir($src); 
    @mkdir($dst); 
    while(false !== ( $file = readdir($dir)) ) { 
        if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) { 
            if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) { 
                recurse_copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
            else { 
                copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($dir); 
} 

recurse_copy($src,$dst);

echo "<H3>Copy Paste completed!</H3>"; //output when done
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a wrong value for the destination argument when the file is a directory. If you want a flat directory structure, it should be just:

```
recurse_copy($src . '/' . $file, $dst);
```

instead of:

```
recurse_copy($src . '/' . $file, $dst . '/' . $file);
```